# Python list in for loop

Tags: python

I have a very simple example of for loop in Python:

```py
for el in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
    print(el)
```

I know that in for loop interpretator calls `__iter__` from list to get list iterator.

I have some questions:

1. Are all elements of this list stored in memory before the beginning for loop?
2. Please explain how the for loop works in this case. What is the deep mechanism of for loop?

Comment: Yes, as soon as you created a list literal, all of the elements of the list are stored in memory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do Python's iterables really store all values in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619152/do-pythons-iterables-really-store-all-values-in-memory)

Comment: You might be interested in the `dis` package as well as these answers

Answer (score 0):

let's imagine Python as a friend reading a list [1, 2, 3, 4] aloud. It starts from the beginning and reads each number, one by one. Every time it reads a number, it "prints" it out

About your memory question: Yes, the list [1, 2, 3, 4] is stored in memory. It's like having the whole list written down on a piece of paper before your friend starts reading.

Answer (score 0):

The semantics of a `for` loop can be expressed using a `while` loop and explicit calls to `next`.

Your loop

```
for el in [1,2,3,4]:
    print(el)
```

could be written as

```
itr = iter([1,2,3,4])
while True:
    try:
        el = next(itr)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    print(el)
del itr
```

`itr` is a value of type `list_iterator` which *wraps* an otherwise anonymous list `[1,2,3,4]`. Each value of the list is in memory, but you can only access them via `itr` by calling `next` (or calling `itr.__next__` explicitly).

A list provides random access to its elements via `list.__getitem__`. A `list_iterator` does not. As far as I know, there is no way to access the underlying list of a `list_iterator`; you can *only* use `__next__` to access the element an internal reference points to.